# How do I do a look up from a user table where the user can be in two columns of the record?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join

This is a very simple idea and want to validate my approach.

I have a record that has the following:

**RESERVATIONS**

| ID | OWNER | RESIDENT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | VLL | MLL |
| 2 | MLL | CVLL |

The lookup table looks like this:

**USER_TABLE**

| PLID | USER_CD | BRANCH |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1a | VLL | USA |
| 2a | MLL | UK |

I want to look up the value in the second table for owner and resident.
You cannot join the ID's together because they are not related. The only relation is from owner to USER_CD

Currently, I do the following:

```
Select CASE
  when reservations.owner = 'VLL' then 1.user_cd
  when reservations.owner = 'MLL' then 2.user_cd
end as 'Location'

FROM RESERVATIONS r
Join USER_TABLE 1
on RESERVATIONS.OWNER = 1.USER_CD
join USER_TABLE 2
ON RESERVATIONS.RESIDENT = 2.USER_CD
```

Is this a correct way to do it or is there another way?

Here is an example implementation:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=92f6178194a7e67f15652cbe7cc549c1

Comment: What's your expected result?

Comment: The join us ok, but I'm not so sure about your case for the location ... Because what would be the result of location, if the owner is located in the US and the resident in UK. Then none of your cases will be met. What do you want to express with that location field in the result?

Comment: sorry folks. I did this from memory and changed it a bit because I think if I send you the actual table, it will be proprietary. It actually works in my working code but I wanted to make sure that I couldn't do this another way. I have to create two alias joins to the same table because on the record, RESERVATIONS and OWNER will be both users but they could be different but they join to that USER_TABLE. I check for whether the user_cd = 'UK' then I make an output in the case. It can be anything.

Comment: If you can't share real data, create example data that demonstrates the behaviours you're dealing with. The literal values could be fairy princess names for all we care. But, if you can't generate example data, including ***both*** the example source ***and*** the desired results, we can't be sure what you want and can't test out answers. Being able to generate example data for testing is a core skill for any developer.

Comment: Put what is needed to ask in your post, not just at a link. [mre]

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use numerals as table aliases. That's even worse than using arbitrary letters. The aliases should still Mean something to anyone reading or debugging the code.

Second, if you want to translate short branch names to long brnach names, the best way is to have another table with those lookups.  In the code below I create that as an inline view (sub-query), though a real table with indexes would be Significantly better.

Then, I believe you're very close already...

```
WITH
  branch_long_name(
    name,
    long_name
  )
AS
(
            SELECT 'USA', 'United States'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'UK',  'United Kingdom'
  -- Note; the UK and Great Britain are not the same
),
  branch
AS
(
  SELECT
    t.*,
    COALESCE(n.long_name, t.branch)   AS long_name
  FROM
    user_table   AS t
  LEFT JOIN
    branch_long_name   AS n
      ON n.name = t.branch
)
SELECT
  r.*,
  b_o.long_name   AS owner_location,
  b_r.long_name   AS resident_location
FROM
  reservations   AS r
LEFT JOIN
  branch   AS b_o   -- branch_owner
    ON b_o.user_cd = r.owner
LEFT JOIN
  branch   AS b_r   -- branch_resident
    ON b_r.user_cd = r.resident
```

Demo : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7cc940ddf40e7cd085cff0fa02b65449

Comment: Rather than a CTE, I would have to do this with a sub query. Is it best practice to make two joins on the same table using a table alias on the join? Is there something wrong by doing that?

Comment: @Axwack - Why on earth does it ***have*** to be a sub-query?  *(Edit you question and explain that in there, not in comments on answers.)*

Comment: I meant to say, in your example, I would have to translate this to a CTE. I have joins in my original query. I apologize, if you saw the query, you would see it as more complicated than this. I just want to confirm if it's ok and best practice to have two joins to a user_table with two aliases on the join.

Comment: @Axwack - There is nothing wrong with joining to the same table twice.  And to do that you have to use aliases *(to avoid ambiguity)*.  As for translating it to a CTE ; It already ***is*** a CTE...

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: @Axwack - Please upvote and/or accept answers that have helped or solved you problem.

Comment: Thanks. Will do and here is how I did it in my code. It's been a while since I'm now doing the queries on my system. Here it is an how it was implemented https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=92f6178194a7e67f15652cbe7cc549c1

Comment: @Axwack - In your fiddle you join on `u1`, then never use it, making the join completely redundant.  And ***please*** do not rename the `UK` to `GB`, they're ***not*** the same thing.  **UK** = `United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland`.  `Great Britain` is the mainland Island, and does not include Northern Ireland, or any of the other islands in the UK.